# Numerology of the ages of the patriarchs

Tags: genesis, numerology

The Bible sporadically lists the years lived by the patriarchs: e.g., 930 years for Adam, 912 for Seth, ... 120 years for Moses.
A complete table is available here [biblical numerology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_numerology#Ages_of_the_Patriarchs):

| # | Patriarch | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | 930 |
| 2 | Seth | 912 |
| 3 | Enosh | 905 |
| 4 | Kenon | 910 |
| 5 | Mehalalel | 895 |
| 6 | Jared | 962 |
| 7 | Enoch | 365 |
| 8 | Methuselah | 969 |
| 9 | Lamech | 777 |
| 10 | Noah | 950 |
| 11 | Shem | 600 |
| 12 | Arpachshad | 438 |
| 13 | Shelah | 433 |
| 14 | Eber | 464 |
| 15 | Peleg | 239 |
| 16 | Reu | 239 |
| 17 | Serug | 230 |
| 18 | Nahor | 148 |
| 19 | Terah | 205 |
| 20 | Abraham | 175 |
| 21 | Isaac | 180 |
| 22 | Jacob | 147 |
| 23 | Levi | 137 |
| 24 | Kohath | 133 |
| 25 | Amram | 137 |
| 26 | Moses | 120 |

These ages sum to 12,600 which, according to that same source is a significant numbers.

I have two questions regarding this. Firstly, what is the significance of the number 12,600? Secondly, is there any significance in the individual ages themselves or is the total the only number of significance?

Comment: The second question seems truncated ("*or is the ?*").

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: @IñakiViggers Thank you for pointing that out. I have amended my question

Comment: "930 + 912 + etc. = 12,600".  That's difficult to verify or deny.  Please provide the details of what "etc." means (ideally with explicit scriptural quotations) rather than expecting each individual reader to do the research.

Comment: "*is the total the only number of significance?*" — There is nothing in the question to indicate that this number *is* a number of significance.

Comment: @RayButterworth Thank you, I have now amended my question

Comment: Why stop at Moses or why not include joseph and go further.  This question has no basis.

Comment: This sort of question has no objective boundaries.  For example, why is the sum of the first 10 patriarchs 8575 which is 25 x 7 x 7 x 7?  Does the age of Lamech (777) have some special significance here?  It all descends into imagination rather than Bible truth in the end.  I do not like anything that is associated with Kabalism.

Comment: Agree with @Dottard. There is a lot of numerical symbolism in the Bible, but it needs to have some basis -- why pick these men? Now what would be interesting is if you could show that some men were related to something that was associated to a number, and their ages summed to the same number, but I don't see that here.

Comment: @Dottard  "*I do not like anything that is associated with Kabalism*". So far I have never seen a reliable resource for ruling out that kabalistic numerology is one example of what Dr. William Barrick [calls](https://drbarrick.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Exegetical-Fallacies.pdf) "*The Fallacy of Reading between The Lines*". But assertions like "*It all descends into imagination rather than Bible truth in the end*" might turn out to instantiate a "*Fallacy of Ignoring Particles*" and/or "*Superior Knowledge Fallacy*".